# Problem with installing tensorflow on windows along with pytorch using conda environment

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, python-3.7

I am trying to install "Tensorflow" on windows using conda environment.

Please note that -

1. I am installing tensorflow along with pytorch in the same environment.
2. I am getting "Remove Error":  'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
   conda's operating environment.
3. I getting this error with both of these commands

   - pip install tensorflow
   - conda install tensorflow

A snap of the error can be seen below.

[image: Error recieved while installing tensorflow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this issue by fixing the installation of the "httptools".

I recently found that many of the conda supports of have been migrated to conda forge.

HENCE, BEFORE INSTALLING THE TENSORFLOW. I INSTALLED THE "httptool" using the following command in the anaconda prompt.

```
conda install -c conda-forge httptools
```

Now everything works really fine.